# Playing FLV files on local share drive from Intranet site

Tags: flash, jwplayer

We would like to build a flash video player into our corporate intranet site, currently we are evaluating JW Player and have come across and issue accessing the FLV files stored on a mirrored share drive that all users have access to on the local intranet.

From what I can tell the Adobe flash plugin will not allow a SWF file hosted 'online' (intranet) to access a shared directory that the user has access to. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I guess you can do it by changing the global security settings and add the swf hosted domain to the trusted one.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Flash security requires all files to come from the same source protocol. This means you can load both the player SWF and the file from HTTP or over your network drive, but you can't mix and match.

Also worth noting that if you run it locally (in this case from a shared network drive), you'll get a Flash security warning by default, but the video *should* play.

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video